# Plotting raw data from census bureau with matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I am trying to analyze some income statistics data from the census bureau. I downloaded the data from: [US census data](https://www.census.gov/data/tables/time-series/demo/income-poverty/cps-hinc/hinc-01.html)

Once I downloaded the data, I transposed it in excel, turned it into a csv file, and then loaded into python using csv reader. I wanted to make a simple bar plot to visualize the data before I got onto more complicated statistical analyses. I am still stuck on the simple bar plot.

The data is simple, the first column is the tax brackets and it is data type 'str'. For example: 'Under $5,000', '$5,000 to  $9,999',...

The second column is number of households, and it is data type 'int'.

I keep getting an error "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"

I thought that by making an array the size of my string list, that I could plot the data and just put the tax bracket information in the 'xticks'. What am I doing wrong?

I am literally using the exact same format as this: [bar plot](https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-bar-chart/)

I am really unfamiliar with pandas and I don't want to use that because it is going to open another can of worms for me. Does anyone have a regular old python fix?

please don't skip steps or assume that I am smart.

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Make empty lists to put data into
brackets = []
households = []

# import raw data into lists
with open("income_data_2017.csv") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            brackets.append(row[0])
            households.append(row[1])

# Check that data was imported correctly
print brackets
print households

# Make an array the correct length for bar plot
x = np.arange(len(brackets))

# Plot the data using the string of income brackets
plt.bar(x, households, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(x, brackets)
plt.title('Distribution of Income in United States, 2017')
plt.ylabel('Households')
plt.xlable('Income Brackets')
```

Comment: You say "The second column is number of households, and it is data type 'int'." but that is not reflected in your code. You would need to convert it to `int` like `households.append(int(row[1]))`.

Comment: It throws an error when I try to do that. I figured out the problem, though. There were commas in the thousands spot in the data, so python didn't recognize the type. Thanks for the help.